# Crystal Report 2005 shows error "failed to load database information, the database dll 'crdbfielddef.dll' could not be loaded"

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, ms-access-2007

I am using visual studio 2008, crystal report 2005 and access database. When I convert one old project to 2008 version, it works fine. But when I open crystal report the error shows " failed to load database information,The database dll 'crdbfielddef'. I installed crystal report runtime engine and all dll and ocx files.. please help me

Comment: try to register your OCX file manually using reg32 in run if not  let me know. furthermore check your access file in correct path

Comment: Registered ocx files using regsvr32. And path is correct..